# Angular - Is there a way to project content inside of ng-template?

Tags: angular, templates, angular2-template

Say I have this ng-template:

```
<!--Tooltip template wrapper-->
<ng-template #toolTipWrapper let-tooltipData>
  <span tooltip="{{tooltipData}}" placement="bottom">
    <!-- How do I get content here?-->
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

and I want to be able to project content inside of that `<span>` like the following:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="toolTipWrapper;context:tooltipData">
  <div> Here is the content I want inside of the span!</div>
</ng-container>
```

Is there a way to do this?

I am using Angular 7 if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another template for that.

```
<!--Tooltip template wrapper-->
<ng-template #toolTipWrapper let-tooltipData="td" let-tooltipContent="tc">
    <span tooltip="{{tooltipData}}" placement="bottom">
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="tooltipContent">
        </ng-container>
    </span>
</ng-template>

<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="toolTipWrapper"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ td: tooltipData, tc: anotherTemplate }">
</ng-container>

<ng-template #anotherTemplate>
    <div> Here is the content I want inside of the span!</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Hmm this accomplishes the goal of not having to copy paste wrapper code everywhere although it does feel kind of unintuitive. Oh well - Angular can be weird sometimes. Thanks!